# install pip on windows using easy_install

Tags: python, windows, pip

I installed python 2.7 on windows 10
and then i installed easy_install
Now i want install pip using easy_install, it show me below error:

C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install -U pip

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install -U pip
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: _ssl.c:484: The handshake operation timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: _ssl.c:484: The handshake operation timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')

C:\Python27\Scripts>
```

Comment: Could be a firewall, or an outdated ssl library that Python 2 is compiled against.

Comment: I assume you have old code you want to run, and that it's not (easily) convertible to Python 3. Otherwise, avoid Python 2, and use Python 3 instead.

Comment: @9769953 yes, its old version and i still need to use python 2.7

Comment: @9769953 there is no any solution?

Comment: `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`

Comment: C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named ensurepip